# Classical Morse Theory

Tags: homotopy-theory

In the early sixties Smale has proved that any simply connected, torsion free differential manifold of dimension greater than 5 has a perfect Morse function. This, incidentally, also solves the Poincare's problem for the higher dimensions.
With the results of Perelman, I wonder: has the dimension limitation been now removed?

Comment: There still  are issues in dimension $4$.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to know what the positive result is, what is known to be true, i.e. for what dimensions it is true and what is the pertinent reference.

Comment: The $h$-cobordism theorem that Smale proved in dimensions $>4$ is known to be false in dimension $4$.  Perleman's result shows that  any simply connected $3$-manifold is diffeomorphic to a $3$-sphere. In dimension $4$ it is not known if a smooth  $4$-manifold homeomorphic to a $4$-sphere is actually diffeomorphic to a $4$-sphere.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not answer my question whether the Smale's theorem above  which was proved for dimensions greater than 5 is now proved to be true for lower dimensions, e.g. for n=5? If so, is there a specific reference for this result?